# Powershell formatting in an culture independent way?! for numbers

Tags: powershell, formatting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, culture

When I use formatting for numbers bigger than 1000 like this :

```
"{0:F2}" -f 1000
```

I get this `1000.00` result for a US system language

and I get this `1000,00` result for a DE (german) system language.

Now I want to avoid that `,` without using `replace ",","."`  or something.

So how to get a culture independent formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ToString` along with `CultureInfo` set to `en-US`, e.g.:

```
$a = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
$b = 1000
$b.ToString("0.00", $a)
```